# How to separate a category in a django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I get this error:
ValueError at /product/
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

this is my models :

```
class Categorie (models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.category_slug 

class Products(models.Model): 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, 
     related_name="product")
    product_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True )
    product_describe = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    product_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='img_pro' , null=True)
    product_created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    product_updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.product_slug
```

this is my view:

```
    def index(requset):    
        category = Categorie.objects.all() 
        product = Products.objects.filter(category_slug=category)  
        context = {
              'category':category,
              'product ':product ,
        }
        return render( requset , 'product/index.html' , context)
```

this is my template:

```
{% for cat in category %}                   
      <div class="fix single_content">           
      <h2>{{cat.title}}</h2>         
      <div class="fix">  
        {% for pro in product %}         
        <ul>
          <li>
           <div class="entry_name"><a href=""><img src="{{pro.product_picture.url}}" alt=""><span>  
           {{pro.product_title}}</span></a><h6>{{pro.product_name}}</h6></div>
          </li>  
        </ul>           
        {% endfor %}                              
      </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

this is myapp.urls:

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views
urlpatterns = [    
path('' , views.index , name='index' ),    
]
```

Can anyone help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

in you index view you are passing a everything you have in vategory

```
category = Categorie.objects.all()
```

while it is expecting just one thing

```
category = Categorie.objects.get(id=pk) # pk or category_id or slug or whatever you named it in your url
```

so your view should look like

```
def index(requset,pk):    
    category = Categorie.objects.get(id=pk) 
    product = Products.objects.filter(category=category)  
    context = {
          'category':category,
          'product ':product ,
    }
    return render( requset , 'product/index.html' , context)
```

Comment: But it gives me an error in my app.urls > this is my urls:

Comment: what cand of error?  what does it say? also can you add you urls ?

Comment: TypeError at /product/
index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Comment: You need to pass pk. change url to this : /product/<int:pk>/

Comment: that is why i said use  pk or category_id or slug or whatever you named it in your url ,so you adapt your urls to the views, you Need a url for Category, there is no way Django can know by itself the category you choose

Comment: it gives me Page not found (404)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get products for a single category use this:

```
category = Categorie.objects.filter(category_slug='<slug-to-search>').first() 
product = Products.objects.filter(category=category)
```

But if you want the product for multiple categories use this:

```
categories = Categorie.objects.all() 
products = Products.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
```

Comment: It retrieves all products in the database and duplicates them for every category

Comment: Yes, It will retrieve all the products. Do you want products by category?
If yes then it will be better to use category.product.all()

Comment: Anywhere it can be used

Comment: not yet . Anywhere it can be used category.product.all()